# Is there any way to get the statement throws the exception in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

I am writing a class in order to handle exceptions in a professional way. I have found the following methods:

```
internal string GetData(Exception x)
    {
        try
        {
            return
                "Message : " + GetMessage(x) + Environment.NewLine +
                "Name Space : " + GetNameSpace(x) + Environment.NewLine +
                "Class Path : " + GetClassPath(x) + Environment.NewLine +
                "Method Name : " + GetMethodName(x) + Environment.NewLine +
                "Line number : " + GetLineNumber(x);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

All of the above informations can be get by using `substring` method on `x.StackTrace`. I need one more information and that is:

> what command is rising exception?

For example I need to see `int.Parse("");` that throws exception.

Is there anyway for that? If anyone has a source code for that, I will thanks him/her for giving me a link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a first function in Stack trace isn't it ?

Comment: What you ask for is in the general case simply not possible. In most cases it will be the first location in the stack trace but in the general case you probably want to distinguish your own code from the framework code and this information is not stored in the stack trace, save for namespace names and such. So you would have to implement a piece of code that would look at the stack trace and determine what the most "interesting" location would be to you. This is difficult to get right, and there is no code in the .NET runtime for this.

Comment: For instance, for `int.Parse` the actual exception is thrown two methods deeper, in a method named `System.Number.StringToNumber`, which is unlikely to be of interest to you. Additionally, in a release build the call to `int.Parse` is optimized away completely, resulting in an inlined call to `System.Number.ParseInt32`. In other words, you cannot get what you want in the general case, and not even in the specific case you are asking for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very easy to do, but doable with some fiddling.

Here is a sample call stack:

> at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>
> at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>
> at SO.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SO\SO\Program.cs:line 29

You notice that the first line in the call stack *with line number* is the last line in our code. So, if you parse every line of the stack trace, then check if it contains a line number, you know that the line *above* that is the method call you have made. That doesn't give the exact code at that line, but at least should give you the method signature.

Comment: Note that `int.Parse` is not actually part of the stack trace. You will likely have to build knowlegde into the code that does this to know that `System.Number.ParseInt32` *most likely* corresponds to `int.Parse`.

Comment: Can I get the source statement by knowing class and line number?

Comment: Not with any existing code, no. Would it be possible to write code to do this? At the very least it would be very hard. Off the top of my head I would think that you would need to read the .pdb file to get debugging information, link that to the IL code, decompile the IL code and then hope you can piece together something that would be useful. In short, no. And again, as you can see from my comment to your question, in a release build there may not even be a call to `int.Parse` at all.

Comment: OK at least I will not spend more time on what is impossible.  I will write some code to send `System.Number.ParseInt32` and `System.Number.StringToNumber`.Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Be careful with the suggestion Patrick makes here. There may not be a line in the stacktrace with a line number at all. If for instance you input something in a wpf application, that causes a binding exception, there will be no user code involved. The same goes for some exceptions in wcf services.

Comment: Jakob is right. Going 100% on this is a little dangerous, it is likely to be that line, but not necessarily.